# Need to enable button when text is entered in field.

Tags: javascript, html

I need to enable my button when I type text into my text box. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
<body>
<script>
  function IsEmpty(){ 
    if(input1.value!=null){
      sendbutton.enabled==true;
    }
  }
  IsEmpty();   
</script>

<input class="draft" name="input1" type="text"/> 
     <button class="send" id="sendbutton" disabled>  Send </button> 
     <ul class="messages">
     </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to add some javascript handling event in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you **JavaScript** to:

```
var input1 = document.getElementById('input1'),
    sendbutton = document.getElementById('sendbutton');
function IsEmpty(){ 
  if (input1.value){
    sendbutton.removeAttribute('disabled');
  } else {
    sendbutton.addAttribute('disabled', '');
  }
}

input1.onkeyup = IsEmpty;
```

And **HTML**:

```
<input class="draft" id="input1" type="text"/> 
<button class="send" id="sendbutton" disabled>Send</button>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/dorefewe/2/edit)

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted `sendbutton.enabled=true;`, with a single `=`. What you've written checks whether they are equal (`false`, presumably), and then doesn't do anything with the result.

Answer (score 0):

To modify an element at the DOM you need either to use pure Javascript's functionality, let's say getElementById function, or any other Javascript framework.

document.getElementById('sendbutton')

Then refer to the attribute and change it.

You can also use JQuery which will help you heaps. I mean, using selectors.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to assign an id to your input element.
<input class="draft" name="input1" id='input1' type="text"/> 

and in your javascript access it like this:

if(document.getElementById('input1').value != null || document.getElementById('input1').value!='undefined'){
  document.getElementById('sendbutton').disabled=false;
}
```