# Text field validation during text entry

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm getting to grips with the text field functions that allow you to check for when "didEndEditing" or "shouldStartEditing" take place.

I've got this working fine when I have 2 text fields and one button.  If I want to enable the button after some validation has taken place I use "didEndEditing" to do some validation and enable the button if everything is okay when the user clicks into the other field.

**Problem**  If you have only one text field and one button on a page, where I require only integers be allowed for the input in the text field before enabling the button, how do I achieve this?

i.e. button is disabled.  As I input text into the text field, if only integers then enable button.  If anything else don't, in real time as you are typing.

As there is only one text field, I don't think I can use "didEndEditing" because you never 'leave' the text field (there's nothing else to click on)

**What have I tried**  I've tried this :

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    print("While entering the characters this method gets called")
    if textField === timeInputField {

//set which characters are valid
        let invalidCharacters = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789").inverted


//if text isn't empty then hide the error label ("must input a time")             
        if timeInputField.text?.isEmpty == false {
            timeInputErrorLabel.isHidden = true
        }

//if the string returns values in the range set button to enabled
        return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: invalidCharacters, options: [], range: string.startIndex ..< string.endIndex) == nil
    } else {
        doWorkoutButtonOutlet.isEnabled = true
    }
    return true
}
```

I think i'm essentially trying to achieve this [Need to enable button when text is entered in field.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466430/need-to-enable-button-when-text-is-entered-in-field) in Swift 4!

Comment: you should be using the key down event handler to look at the key. If the key is not a number, you interrupt the event and the illegal character is not put in the box.

Comment: Why would the button ever be disabled if you never allow the user to enter invalid characters? The whole point of using `shouldChangeCharactersIn` as shown in your question is that invalid characters can't be entered. Since the text field will never have invalid characters, the button never needs to be disabled.

Comment: @rmaddy what about if the user hasn’t entered anything though?

Comment: Then enable the button any time the text changes to a non-empty value.

Comment: thanks @rmaddy - although, just to clarify your earlier comment, when I load the simulator with the code I have, the user can still enter characters.  i.e. it doesn't stop the characters being entered into the input field?  Is that what you expect is happening with my code when you say "invalid characters can't be entered?"

Comment: The code you posted should prevent invalid characters (non-numbers) from being entered into your `timeInputField`.

Comment: Check out this [solution](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2016/09/05/swift-3-text-field-magic-part-1-creating-text-fields-with-maximum-lengths/). It works well and may be a good fit in your case.

Comment: @rmaddy you were right - i'd stupidly forgotten to set my text field as the delegate so it does in fact block input that isn't a number

Answer (score 1):

This will prevent anything other than integers entering the `textField`. Don’t forget to do a check for which `textField` if using more than one.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
    if numbers.contains(string ?? "") {
        // Validate text for button enabling
        if let stringValue = textField.text {
            if let number = Int(stringValue) {
                yourButton.isEnabled = true
                // Text validated as an integer. Can use value of number if desired
            } else {
                yourButton.isEnabled = false
            }
        } else {
            yourButton.isEnabled = false
        }
        // Return true to update field with new character
        return true
    } else {
        // Return false as entered character is not a digit 0-9
        return false
    }
}
```

You can also validate text in this delegate method:

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if let stringValue = textField.text {
        if let number = Int(stringValue) {
            yourButton.isEnabled = true
            // Do something with number value
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked. The question already has valid code for ensuring only numbers are entered. And your use of `as? Int` will never work since a `String` can never be cast to an `Int`.

Comment: Again you are right @rmaddy I have edited to add button enabling and constructing an integer from string with `Int(string)`

Comment: @Chris thanks for this but it gets a "Use of unresolved identifier 'replacementString'" on the line.. if numbers.contains(replacementString).  You just need to remove "string" after "replacementString" before ": String" in your answer I think.

Comment: Sorry `replacementString` should be `string` :)

Comment: Thanks - I think the problem with this method though is that it relies on "did end editing".  Where there is only one text field, there is nowhere to 'click out' of the button - so the editing never finishes.  Is there a way to validate in real time as you are typing?

Comment: `shouldChangeCharacters` is called with every key press. You could check and validate the `textField.text` each time it is called and enable or disable button. I’ll update answer.

Comment: I have updated answer. Now just use my version of `shouldChangeCharacters()` - it is meant for validating text as you are typing. I have updated it to also check the whole text to make sure it is an integer and enable the button if so.

Comment: thanks but I get a couple more errors on latest code.  I think there's a return function missing at the end and there's a "numbers was never used, consider replacing with boolean test" on the "if let numbers = Int(StringValue)" section.  There's also a duplicate (i think) of "else { yourbutton.isenabled = false". Thanks for helping so far!

Comment: No problem :) The value `number` was provided as a result of the second `if let` statement. It can be used if needed, such as assigned to a global variable etc. My code did not use it. The repeat of `yourButton.isEnabled = false` was because of the nested `if else` statements, to ensure every possibility is covered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171876/discussion-between-nc14-and-chris).